# TapGesture on SwiftUI Scrollable Chart (iOS 17.0)

Tags: swiftui-charts

I'm trying to detect `TapGesture` on `BarMark` on SwiftUI Chart (iOS 17.0), but unsuccessfully.
I'm aware that I can use the `chartXSelection` modifier but it reacts on drag gestures which collides with scrolling and leads to not very best user experience.

Do you have any suggestions?
Thanks

```
var body: some View {
        Chart {
            ActivitiesChartContent(activities: $activities)
            
            HistoryDataChartContent(quantities: $quantities)
        }
        .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
        .chartXSelection(value: $rawSelectedDate)
        .onChange(of: rawSelectedDate) { oldValue, newValue in
            guard let newValue,
                  let activity = activities.first(where: { ($0.startDate...$0.endDate).contains(newValue) }) else { return }
            
            onTap?(activity)
        }
    }
```

I tried:

1. Overriding `chartGesture`, but I couldn't find a way to detect `TapGesture` location.
2. Using `chartOverlay` as suggested in other threads, but it doesn't contain the whole frame so it can't detect the real location